# Hook into TextBox of other app (productivity)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, winapi

I am creating an aid that will help me be more productive while doing certain things and I need to monitor input in external apps (apps that are not ones that I made) on the Desktop (not metro) and watch for certain symbols being inputted into the textbox, and if they match what I've added to a list, my app will replace that particular input in the external app with something else that I've set.

How can we watch input in a given external app on the desktop? Do programs have messages (like W_MSG I think it is) where a message is sent when the user inputs into the textbox?

Comment: You would have better luck hooking the keyboard than attempting to monitor all input controls currently active on the desktop.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead true, but then I'd need to worry too much about parsing  char by char as the input comes in, wouldn't I? Where as with WM_GETTEXT I can just get the text in the control as a whole string and like, just do a tb.Replace(str, "newContent");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported route for a scenario like this would be UI Automation (see [UI Automation Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx)). It is the successor to Microsoft's Active Accessiblity and provides programmatic access to GUI elements and events.

[UI Automation Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748252.aspx) gives a short overview of available events you can subscribe to. [TextPattern.TextChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.textpattern.textchangedevent.aspx) is a promising candidate to subscribe to.

UI Automation is supported for all Windows standard controls. If your external app uses a GUI library that is not based on Windows controls (like Qt) you cannot use UI Automation.

Comment: Thank you very much @IInspectable. I finally have a reason to use UI Automation in .net